# How to find list of of successfully sent emails in EXM

Tags: exm

A client has recently had an issue come up during a email campaign blast in EXM. They experienced an error at some point during the process of sending out emails and the statistics show that they only sent out about 25% of the planned emails.

Is there a way to figure out exactly which email contacts are associated with those successful emails? The idea would be to build an exclusion list and try the email blast again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, up to and including EXM 3.4.2, if anything happens during dispatch and all recipients cannot be processed, the message will be moved to the "Paused" state and the campaign can be retried - meaning EXM will process the recipients that have not already received the email.

You can also extract the data of who the campaign has not been sent to. Look in the DispatchQueue table of the exm database. Query by message id and you'll get a list of all the contacts that have not received the email.

If you're working with EXM 3.3 or later, EXM creates an interaction at the time of dispatch for every recipient, allowing you can to query xDB to determine who the mail has been sent to. Look for interactions with the "Email Sent" page event. This tells you who the email has been sent to, but not that it was actually received e.g. it may have hard bounced.